# How to use a monger connection globally in the server?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I have a mongodb database that I've connected to like so:

```
(let [uri  (config-keys :mongoURI)
      {:keys [conn db]} (mg/connect-via-uri uri)])
```

In Node.js with mongoose, one can do `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`, to connect to the database only once and then use it from any of the files in the global namespace. How do I do this with monger so that I don't have to repeat the code above in each file that uses the database and instead connect with it only once?

Answer (score 0):

So your question could be generalized to: How do I manage global state in my application.

There are several libs which help you do this:

1. [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) which lets you create a map of global state which you pass to the functions that need them
2. [mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) which lets you create something akin to global variables
3. [integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant)

You can also do this without any specific libs, using middleware (assuming you're using [ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring)):

```
(defn add-db-to-req [handler uri]
  (fn [req]
    (let [connection (mg/connect-via-uri uri)]
      (handler (assoc req :connection connection)))))
```

Any middleware downstream from this can access the connection by

```
(:connection req)
```

and pass it along to the functions which need it.

In general, instead of depending on global state, you will want to pass the `connection` along to any function that depends on it as such:

```
(defn fetch-from-database [{:keys [db conn] :as connection} whatever]
  ...)
```

Comment: The last paragraph is the key: "In general, instead of depending on global state, you will want to pass the connection [not username and password] along to any function that depends on it".

Comment: @slipset, would you please explain the last part of your answer? How do I pass in the connection if it is in another file into a function without using global states?

Comment: Something like this https://gist.github.com/slipset/c405bbb27f77eb5215eca4a365eb359a